# Visio 2013: How to reduce width of built-in UML class shape?

Tags: visio, office-2013

I drew a class diagram of the type 'UML static structure' with Visio 2013. Now I would like to reduce the width of the class shapes in the diagram. I removed the size protection in the developer tools section and also tried to set the width in the corresponding shape sheet but nothing worked.
Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 25):

In Visio 2013, you can change class width using a control point (yellow dot), just drag it:
[image]

Comment: That hint worked for me, though its extremely tricky to hit the yellow dot without getting Visio to show an orange line. The orange line is used, when double clicked, to add an attribute member.
Note: as soon this line is visible the resizing is not possible anymore.

Comment: Wow, I literally spent like half an hour on this, because resizing those shapes is blocked. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: me, too!  
It's still like that in Visio 2019, albeit with a bigger blob.

Comment: This did not work for me in Visio Pro 2019, the yellow thingy moves but not the shape. Ali Nazem answer below worked though, lasso selecting the whole shape and unprotecting the size

Answer (score 5):

The class shape is composed of a group of objects. You should drag your mouse over it to select not only the external shape, but also all the elements inside it such as the ClassName text and any possibly existing members, etc. 
Now, if you remove the size protection as you mentioned, this will apply to all the elements, and then you can change the size using "Size & Position" task pane. (Ribbon --> View --> Show --> Task Panes)